# Read *.csproj property values using Roslyn APIs?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am currently building a tool which will support the development of an ASP.NET Core project. This tool uses the Roslyn APIs and other methods for verifying some development requirements (such as project-specific attributes being applied on API Controllers, enforcing naming conventions, and generating some source code for the JavaScript SPA which accesses an API written using the ASP.NET Core Web API template).

In order to do that, I am currently using hardcoded paths to generate code for the SPA app. But in the app's ***.csproj** file there is actually a "SpaRoot" property specifying where the SPA application is located inside the project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

**My question is:** how can I read the "SpaRoot" property's value using the Roslyn APIs?

I have written a minimum code sample to create a `Workspace`, open the `Solution`, and retrieve the `Project`'s reference, which resembles the following:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string solutionFile = @"C:\Test\my-solution.sln";
    using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
    {
        var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionFile);

        string projectName = "some-project";
        var project = solution.Projects.Single(p => p.Name == projectName);

        // How to extract the value of "SpaRoot" from the Project here?
    }
```

I've tried searching on how to extract the "SpaRoot" property from the `Project` reference, and even went as far as debugging to see if I could spot a way myself. Unfortunately, I came up with no answers to that, and I'm still using hardcoded paths in my original code.

Is it even possible to retrieve the value of **.csproj** properties of a `Project` using the current Roslyn APIs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is more difficult that you would think :) The Roslyn apis only know what the compiler knows and the compiler is not going to be given anything regarding the `SpaRoot` property.  We can use the MSBuild apis to figure this out though. specifically the [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project?view=netframework-4.8) class.

**Some assumptions I am making**

1. You only want to examine .NET Core projects
2. You will have the .NET Core SDK installed on which ever system runs this tool

So first we want a project file that looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <!--NOTE: If the project you are analyzing is .NET Core then the commandline tool must be as well.
              .NET Framework console apps cannot load .NET Core MSBuild assemblies which is required 
              for what we want to do.-->
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>Latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- NOTE: We put ExcludeAssets="runtime" on all direct MSBuild references so that we pick up whatever
               version is being used by the .NET SDK instead. This is accomplished with the Microsoft.Build.Locator
               referenced further below. -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build" Version="16.4.0" ExcludeAssets="runtime" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="2.9.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="3.4.0" />
    <!-- NOTE: A lot of MSBuild tasks that we are going to load in order to analyze a project file will implicitly
               load build tasks that will require Newtonsoft.Json version 9. Since there is no way for us to ambiently 
               pick these dependencies up like with MSBuild assemblies we explicitly reference it here. -->
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and a Program.cs file that looks like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.Build.Construction;
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

// I use this so I don't get confused with the Roslyn Project type
using MSBuildProject = Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project;

namespace loadProject {
    class Program {
        static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            MSBuildWorkspaceSetup();
            // NOTE: we need to make sure we call MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance
            // before we ask the CLR to load any MSBuild types. Therefore we moved
            // the code that uses MSBuild types to its own method (instead of being in
            // Main) so the CLR is not forced to load them on startup.
            await DoAnalysisAsync(args[0]);
        }

        private static async Task DoAnalysisAsync(string solutionPath) {
            using var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

            // Print message for WorkspaceFailed event to help diagnosing project load failures.
            workspace.WorkspaceFailed += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Diagnostic.Message);

            Console.WriteLine($"Loading solution '{solutionPath}'");

            // Attach progress reporter so we print projects as they are loaded.
            var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath, new ConsoleProgressReporter());
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished loading solution '{solutionPath}'");

            // We just select the first project as a demo
            // you will want to use your own logic here
            var project = solution.Projects.First();

            // Now we use the MSBuild apis to load and evaluate our project file
            using var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(File.OpenRead(project.FilePath));
            ProjectRootElement root = ProjectRootElement.Create(xmlReader, new ProjectCollection(), preserveFormatting: true);
            MSBuildProject msbuildProject = new MSBuildProject(root);

            // We can now ask any question about the properties or items in our project file
            // and get the correct answer
            string spaRootValue = msbuildProject.GetPropertyValue("SpaRoot");
        }

        private static void MSBuildWorkspaceSetup() {
            // Attempt to set the version of MSBuild.
            var visualStudioInstances = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().ToArray();
            var instance = visualStudioInstances.Length == 1
                // If there is only one instance of MSBuild on this machine, set that as the one to use.
                ? visualStudioInstances[0]
                // Handle selecting the version of MSBuild you want to use.
                : SelectVisualStudioInstance(visualStudioInstances);

            Console.WriteLine($"Using MSBuild at '{instance.MSBuildPath}' to load projects.");

            // NOTE: Be sure to register an instance with the MSBuildLocator 
            //       before calling MSBuildWorkspace.Create()
            //       otherwise, MSBuildWorkspace won't MEF compose.
            MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance(instance);
        }

        private static VisualStudioInstance SelectVisualStudioInstance(VisualStudioInstance[] visualStudioInstances) {
            Console.WriteLine("Multiple installs of MSBuild detected please select one:");
            for (int i = 0; i < visualStudioInstances.Length; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine($"Instance {i + 1}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    Name: {visualStudioInstances[i].Name}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    Version: {visualStudioInstances[i].Version}");
                Console.WriteLine($"    MSBuild Path: {visualStudioInstances[i].MSBuildPath}");
            }

            while (true) {
                var userResponse = Console.ReadLine();
                if (int.TryParse(userResponse, out int instanceNumber) &&
                    instanceNumber > 0 &&
                    instanceNumber <= visualStudioInstances.Length) {
                    return visualStudioInstances[instanceNumber - 1];
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Input not accepted, try again.");
            }
        }

        private class ConsoleProgressReporter : IProgress<ProjectLoadProgress> {
            public void Report(ProjectLoadProgress loadProgress) {
                var projectDisplay = Path.GetFileName(loadProgress.FilePath);
                if (loadProgress.TargetFramework != null) {
                    projectDisplay += $" ({loadProgress.TargetFramework})";
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"{loadProgress.Operation,-15} {loadProgress.ElapsedTime,-15:m\\:ss\\.fffffff} {projectDisplay}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should note, if you are trying to do something like this from within a Visual Studio extension (or Roslyn code fix) I would take a different approach, VS already has all this information but you will need to access it in a different way

Comment: @Janoth Marolf do you know how to achieve the same (read a Property from the csproj) from within a Roslyn Source Generator? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would look at [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#consume-msbuild-properties-and-metadata) section of the cookbook. If you need more info I would post a separate question